# How to handle q and promise for unit test case

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, sinon

I have one api which has been create using q and promise. I need to write unit test case for that api . but it is not sending response because of that q and promises .
this is my api

```
  exports.test=funtion(req,res)
 {

     savedata(req.body).saveQ().then(function(result)
    {
              res.send(result);
    });
 }
```

this is my test case for the above api

```
 var req={'body':{name:'xxxxx'}};

 var res={};

 describe('savedata',function()
{
      it('should save data',function(){
         spy=res.send=sinon.spy();
        test(req,res);
        expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be('true');
     });        

});
```

can any body tell me how to work it out ?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to test since you're not exposing any way of knowing when the function is done. You need the caller to be aware of it.

I'm assuming this is mocha unit tests:

```
exports.test=funtion(req,res){
    return savedata(req.body).saveQ().then(function(result){ // note the `return`
         res.send(result);
    });
};
```

Which would let you do:

```
it('should save data',function(){
   spy=res.send=sinon.spy();
    return test(req,res).then(function(){  // note the return and the then
        expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be('true');
    });
 });
```